# Using Microsft Graph API for MicroSoft 365 reports

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Given that I have credentials and access is allowed. Can I use the package: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core to query our companies instance of MS 365 to get report queries such as:

Outlook Usage:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/email-activity-reports?view=graph-rest-beta

Service Heath:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-raimportcerts-certificateconnectordetails-gethealthmetrictimeseries?view=graph-rest-beta

User Experience:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-raimportcerts-certificateconnectordetails-gethealthmetrictimeseries?view=graph-rest-beta